# Using <merge><merge/> in conjunction with GestureOverlayView

Tags: java, android, merge, gesture

I have two layouts that I merge for one of my activities. It's necessary that I merge them, otherwise they won't work correctly. I'm trying to add a `GestureOverlayView` to this same activity; however, you apparently can't if you're using the merg tag. Does anyone know how I can use `GestureOverlayView` and still merge my two layouts?

The error I receive is this:

```
01-02 08:32:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(13203): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
<merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
```